# how to properly download bootstrap files and use them in my project

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded the [compiled bootstrap files](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v5.3.0/bootstrap-5.3.0-dist.zip) and then used both `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` and then I called both of them inside my HTML page,

here is how the `bootstrap.min.css` files starting looks like :

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
 * Bootstrap  v5.3.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2023 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
 */
 :root,[data-bs-theme=light]{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;
.........
```

when I try to open the page, first I got this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at bootstrap.min.css:1:1)
```

so that I tried to comment the line manually `@charset "UTF-8";`

after doing this and running again I got this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at bootstrap.min.css:7:2)
```

then I tried to remove the `:` at the first line (which am sure can't be removed but I had to try )

then I tried to run again I got this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (at bootstrap.min.css:7:8)
```

so am kinda stuck now and can't get bootstrap to work .. any help with this?

***NOTE***

please note that am avoiding using CDN URLs because some times the project works offline.

Comment: Please show how you are linking to the stylesheet.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to load the CSS as JS instead as CSS.